# Where did the BIND website go?

Tags: database, interactions

I was trying to reach the [BIND](http://binddb.org) (**B**iomolecular **I**nteraction **N**etwork **D**atabase) but the website is down.

Where can I find something similar? Has this platform moved somewhere or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer from @heathobrien converted from comment:*

looks like that link has been dead for years:

https://www.biostars.org/p/16763/

*Answer from @jason-aller converted from comment:*

The biostars article mentions this:

http://baderlab.org/BINDTranslation